# jQuery - change a script to load on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a geo-location script that triggers when a user hits the "Give me directions" button ".get-directions", this works fine.

```
<div class="dirBtn">10 Street Road, Suburb, Country</div>
<!-- css -->
<style>
p.warning { color: red; }
input.manual-location { width: 95%; font-size: 1.2em; padding: 5px; }
.no-geolocation { display: none; }
.get-directions { background: #000; padding: 8px 13px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 6px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; text-decoration: none; clear: both; display: block; text-align: center; cursor:pointer; width:80%; }
    .get-directions:hover { text-decoration:none;  color: #ffffff; background:#333; font-weight: bold; }
.dirBtn { visibility:hidden; }
</style>

<!-- javascript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var gmap = $('.dirBtn').text();


$(document).ready(function () {

    var startingLocation;
    var destination = gmap.replace(/\s/g,"+")

    $('a.get-directions').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // check if browser supports geolocation
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            // get user's current position
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                // get latitude and longitude
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                startingLocation = latitude + "," + longitude;

                // send starting location and destination to goToGoogleMaps function
                goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination);

            });
        }

            // fallback for browsers without geolocation
        else {

            // get manually entered postcode
            startingLocation = $('.manual-location').val();

            // if user has entered a starting location, send starting location and destination to goToGoogleMaps function
            if (startingLocation != '') {
                goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination);
            }
                // else fade in the manual postcode field
            else {
                $('.no-geolocation').fadeIn();
            }

        }

        // go to Google Maps function - takes a starting location and destination and sends the query to Google Maps
        function goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination) {
            window.location = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + startingLocation + "&daddr=" + destination;
        }

    });

});


</script>
<div class="no-geolocation">
<p class="warning">Your browser does not support Geolocation. Please enter             your postcode and click the button again.</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter postcode or address" class="manual-location">
</div>
<a class="get-directions show" target="_blank">Give me directions</a>
```

What I want to do is put the "Give me directions" button/link on a different page:

Example.

```
<a href="pagename/pagewiththescript" class="get-directions show" target="_blank">Give me directions</a>
```

And modify the script to launch straight away when the page loads, because I didn't write the geo-location script I just need a hand converting it from an "on click" to a "page load".

I hope I explained that clear enough, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Any errors on the console ?

Comment: Only in chrome and only when your trying to run the script on an unsecured URL

Comment: Just put the code directly in the `$(document).ready()` of `pagewiththescript`, instead of inside the `.click()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I was over thinking it.

Comment: That would work, but then you have the same code in several places. If you ever need to edit it, you'd have to track down all those places and change them one at a time. Might be better to have this in a separate file linked to each document

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there is only once instance of the script used but will keep that in mind for other projects.

Comment: In your example, you show 2 explicit instances of the code. See my update below, this makes more sense as a separate function. If you separate the logic, you can reuse this code anywhere and only have to change the variable passed to it and not the function itselt ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this logic in multiple pages in multiple ways, you should really break the code out into its own function. This way you dont have to duplicate any code.

In your original `html` file change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.get-directions').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var gmap = $('.dirBtn').text();
    initMap(gmap); 

  });

});
```

In a separate `.js` file, declare your functions:

```
function initMap(gmap) {
  var startingLocation;
  var destination = gmap.replace(/\s/g, "+")
    // check if browser supports geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    // get user's current position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      // get latitude and longitude
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      startingLocation = latitude + "," + longitude;

      // send starting location and destination to goToGoogleMaps function
      goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination);

    });
  }

  // fallback for browsers without geolocation
  else {

    // get manually entered postcode
    startingLocation = $('.manual-location').val();

    // if user has entered a starting location, send starting location and destination to goToGoogleMaps function
    if (startingLocation != '') {
      goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination);
    }
    // else fade in the manual postcode field
    else {
      $('.no-geolocation').fadeIn();
    }

  }
}
// go to Google Maps function - takes a starting location and destination and sends the query to Google Maps
function goToGoogleMaps(startingLocation, destination) {
  window.location = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + startingLocation + "&daddr=" + destination;
}
```

Link the `.js` file to all documents that need access to the functions

In the `head` tag of the new page.

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      var gmap = 'someValue';
        initMap(gmap); 

   );
</script>
```